Examples of Multi-rotors (Quadrotors) in Ignition-Gazebo?
I am new to Ignition Gazebo. I want to have multiple(4) multi-rotors(quadrotors) following a trajectory. Is it possible to have any example repos to see this behaviour and understand the code structure better. I tried looking into online for open source repo and couldn't find it. Any help in this direction will be very helpful :)

I would suggest skipping the gazebo ignition (gz fortress) and directly move to gzsim (gz garden or gz harmonic)  (note: ign namespace has been changed to gz in the latest versions) as ignition tag is going to be EOL around in September this year.
Also things are not well documented (yet) so if you want to build your own simulation, you will need to dig through a lot of source code to connect the dots and make your own simulation. If not, you can have a look into aerostack2

@aarsht7 thank you for your suggestion. Can you let me know why you suggest to skip fortress and directly go to garden or harmonic ? I am curious to know the reason behind it.

In fortress they use the namespace ign, renamed to gz in the later versions because of some conflict. You can read it in History. For more info, read this post. Fortress is going to be EOL this year so it is better to go with one of the latest versions with gz namespace.

@aarsht7 Thank you for sharing the links. I guess the main point is on the naming and usage based on the name. I guess functionality wise it's not a problem. I did see the End of line for Fortress is 2026 as it is LTS (Long term support). I will try to go for new version like Garden or Humble the only thing is I had to upgrade my ubuntu system from 20.04 to 22.04

Ah yes I got confused between Fortress and Citadel. Anyway Fortress is not supported with ROS Foxy (20.04). So if you want to use that you will have to mkove to 22.04 and Humble version support info here

If you are looking for a multi-vehicle sim, PX4 does have that functionality and has a bit of documentation on how to start it up:
https://docs.px4.io/main/en/sim_gazebo_gz/multi_vehicle_simulation.html
The drones can then get a trajectory passed to them via ROS2 topics for the trajectory setpoint.

I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly...
for the questions, I would suggest aerostack2 or similar things rather than px4 or ardupilot as there is no mention of the hardware side. Plus, if only trajectory following is required in simulation, aerostack2 is easier to set up in that case.

That's awesome. I was looking into Aerostack. It has trajectory tracking and also some controllers. I am looking at examples to get started with it. Do you suggest some examples to understand it more and get started with it ?

If you are not looking for any specific hardware and just want to try simulation, a basic gazebo example or crazyflie example is a good entry point.
